# Distinct not showing the desired output

Tags: mysql

I did quite some searching but could not find a proper answer to have multiple rows and columns in a select query to get the following:

What if you want to select all columns for rows where country is Thailand and you want to skip duplicates from the column city and only select the lowest price from the column total.

How should I apply DISTINCT than? SELECT DISTINCT partner, city, price, fee, total from %tablename%; does not 'remove' the duplicate currently.

```
   partner | country   | city    | price | fee | total

   W       | thailand  | bangkok | 400   | 15  | 415
   X       | vietnam   | hanoi   | 400   | 25  | 425 
   Y       | vietnam   | hanoi   | 300   | 30  | 330
   X       | thailand  | bangkok | 300   | 25  | 325
   Y       | thailand  | bangkok | 298   | 30  | 328
   Y       | thailand  | krabi   | 560   | 15  | 575
   Z       | thailand  | krabi   | 550   | 35  | 585
```

So I would like to have the following:

```
   X       | thailand  | bangkok | 300   | 25  | 325
   Y       | thailand  | krabi   | 560   | 15  | 575
```

Comment: I think your expected output for bangkok is wrong

Comment: you are fully right, I changed it now, thanks!

Comment: partner should be `X` for bangkok in expected output

Comment: You have to play with group by

Comment: Hi. Your question does not contain a clear statement of your question/goal/problem. So why expect googling to help? (Rhetorical.) Take the time & effort & words to clearly say what you mean. When you are clear this will be a faq. Please also read & act on [mcve]. (Which includes a clear specification.) PS There is even a tag for this, greatest-n-per-group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need aggregation using `Group By`:

```
SELECT t1.partner, 
       t1.country, 
       t1.city, 
       t1.price, 
       t1.fee, 
       t1.total 
FROM your_table AS t1 
JOIN (SELECT city, MIN(total) AS min_total 
      FROM your_table 
      WHERE country = 'thailand' 
      GROUP BY city) AS t2 ON t2.city = t1.city 
                          AND t2.min_total = t1.total  
GROUP BY t1.partner, 
         t1.country, 
         t1.city, 
         t1.price, 
         t1.fee, 
         t1.total
```

Comment: @louis Can you get a situation where there is a tie on total price for a ciry? for example X       | thailand  | bangkok | 250   | 75  | 325 ?

Comment: Ooh nice one, than a second 'min'  could be applied and that would be price. So assuming this situation that partner X offers a price of 200, fee of 30 so total of 230 and partner Y woulf offer price 190, fee 40 thus total of 230 than the row of partner Y should be selected.

Comment: It seems that I miss a reference table for t2? Is that correct?

Comment: @Louis what do you mean ? What are you attempting to do ?

Comment: I am actually did put the code into mysql and getting error #1054 - unknow column 't2.country' in where clause. So I was asking myself, where does the t2 in t2.country refer to.

Comment: @Louis it is a typo. Please treat it as country. I am editing it

Answer (score 0):

use co related sub-query which is easy

```
     select * from tablename t 
     where t.total in ( select min(total) from tablename t1
                      where t1.country=t.country
                            and t1.city=t.city
                      group by t1.country,t1.city
                    ) and t.country='thailand'
```